# promising response from angular forEach which is having $timeout within it

Tags: angularjs, foreach, timeout

I have an html button ,which has to be enable or disable based on an scope variable. Am assign that enable/disable action in an for each based on an condition. for that condition I need `$timeout`.

```
vm.isDisable = true;//disbles the button before forEAch
//vm.gridData, which is array  of object haves more than 1000 rows
  angular.forEach(vm.gridData,function(rows){ 
     if(rows.isSelectedRow == true) { 
        $timeout(function(){ 
            vm.gridApi.selection.selectRow(rows); 
         }) 
    });
  vm.isDisable = false; //enables the button after for each
```

But enables the button before the for each completed, because of `$timeout` within the forEach. how can I disable the button during the forEach and enable it back after the iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use promises with `all` method:

```
var promises = [];
vm.isDisable = true;
  angular.forEach(vm.gridData,function(rows){ 
     if(rows.isSelectedRow == true) { 

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        promises.push(deferred.promise);

        $timeout(function(){ 
            vm.gridApi.selection.selectRow(rows); 
            deferred.resolve();
         }) 
    });
$q.all(promises).then(function(){
    vm.isDiable = false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$timeout` returns a promise so you could create an array of those promises and enable button after they have all resolved

```
var promises = vm.gridData.reduce(function(a, c) {
  if (c.rows.isSelectedRow == true) {
    a.push($timeout(function() {
      return vm.gridApi.selection.selectRow(c.rows);
    }));
  }
  return a;
}, []);


$q.all(promises).then(function(){
    vm.isDiable = false;
})
```